# What's the difference between the session cookie and "remember me" feature?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, authentication, cookies

CakePHP automatically creates a cookie, named CAKEPHP. Using the auth component, once logged in, this cookie seems to be the user identifier to the server and you can close the browser and everything and as long as the cookie is there you're still logged in.

Is there a difference with a "remember me" functionality? It seems once you log in you're "remembered" until you log out or the cookie expires anyway.

Thanks indeed

Comment: Pretty much all "remember me" systems work the same way. Some value is stored in a cookie. When the browser returns to the site, that value is matched in the database to see it matches a valid user (preferably checking if that user indeed enabled a "remember me" option, which is just something you keep track off in your database). But yes, its basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

@Damien is right about the mechanism of the "remember me".

But depending on where that value is stored there are some differences.

By default session cookie [php doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) has a lifetime = "until the browser is closed".

If we store that value in $_SESSION by default when the user closes the browser the session cookie is deleted and the value is lost therefore no "remember me" functionality.

If we want to implement remember me functionality using session we have the change the php.ini session cookie lifetime parameter to overwrite expire on browser close behaviour.

On the other hand if we store that value explicitly in $_COOKIE and setting a desired  time to live value we make sure that even if the user closes the browser and comes back we have the Cookie in place and the unique value to identify him.